# how to put 'buy' and 'info' button under multiple image in html?

Tags: html

Here is the image.
[image]

I want to display two buttons, 'buy' and 'image' button, under each images. I want to use html.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now? It already displays two buttons under each image. What do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
} 

div.img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc"><button>Buy</button><button>Image</button></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc"><button>Buy</button><button>Image</button></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc"><button>Buy</button><button>Image</button></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc"><button>Buy</button><button>Image</button></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```